# Python MPI (mpi4py) multiple executables. (MPI server)

Tags: python, server, mpi, mpi4py

I'm trying to develop something similar to a writing server using python.
The concept is that I want to launch 2 process with different number of processors and get communicators between them:

calcul.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from mpi4py import MPI
import sys


def do_calcul():
    calcul_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    calcul_rank = calcul_comm.Get_rank()
    calcul_size = calcul_comm.Get_size()

    print 'Rank {0}/{1} calculation\n'.format(calcul_rank, calcul_size)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_calcul()
```

server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from mpi4py import MPI
import sys


def do_writing():
    server_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    server_rank = server_comm.Get_rank()
    server_size = server_comm.Get_size()

    print 'Rank {0}/{1} writing'.format(server_rank, server_size)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_writing()
```

To run the scripts I want to launch the both scripts:

```
mpirun -np 4 python hs_calcul.py : -np 2 python hs_server.py
```

The problem is that each script doesn't detect their own COMM_WORLD and the output is that:

```
Rank 2/6 calculation

Rank 4/6 writing
Rank 1/6 calculation

Rank 3/6 calculation

Rank 5/6 writing
Rank 0/6 calculation
```

I want to get something like

```
Rank 2/4 calculation

Rank 1/2 writing
Rank 1/4 calculation

Rank 3/4 calculation

Rank 0/2 writing
Rank 0/4 calculation
```

and the way to get the MPI communicator to communicate any of the calculation process to the writing process.

Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: You have to do it manually. First `MPI_Comm_split()` to get both computation and writer communicators, then you might want to create an inter communicator out of them. Make sure you understand inter communicator first, since their usage might seem counter intuitive at the beginning.